# Any set of 3 linearly independent vectors is a basis in $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

In other words, given any $\vec{v} = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$ and a linearly independent set of vectors $\{\vec{x},\vec{y},\vec{z}\}$, there exists $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ such that $\alpha\vec{x} + \beta\vec{y} + \gamma\vec{z} = \vec{v}$.

Now, I've seen people construct the scalars $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ without first showing that they exist.

How do you show the existence of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$?

Comment: By the definition of linearly independent? The existence of the scalars is part of the statement that $x,y,z$ are linearly independent.

Comment: $\{\vec x,\vec y,\vec z,\vec v\}$ is a linearly *dependent* set with $\{\vec x,\vec y,\vec z\}$ a linearly *independent* subset.  Use the definitions to make conclusions.

Comment: Not really, linear independence means there are no scalars (not all zero) such that they sum up to the zero vector, not that there always exists scalars such that they can sum up to a given vector.

Comment: @Bye_World, then you need to show $\{\vec{x},\vec{y},\vec{z},\vec{v}\}$ is a lin. dependent set.

Comment: *I* don't need to show it, I've already done Linear Algebra.  If *you*'ve never proven that any set of $\gt 4$ vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ is always a linearly dependent set, then now's a good time for *you* to prove it.

Comment: Perhaps [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Expression_of_Vector_as_Linear_Combination_from_Basis_is_Unique) has the proof you're looking for.